# Odoo access table inside model using xml-rpc

Tags: xml-rpc, odoo

I am working on an xml-rpc service that needs to read data from a table, **res_groups_users_rel**. But the service is not able to fetch data from that table. I tried the same service on **res_groups** table and it is working fine. Is there a way to access **res_groups_users_rel** table from an xml-rpc service?

Here is the xml-rpc service:

```
Object r2[] = new Object[7];
r2[0] = db;
r2[1] = (Integer) uId;
r2[2] = password;
r2[3] = "res.groups.users.rel";
r2[4] = "read";
r2[5] = moduleId;
Object[] params6 = { "uid", "gid"};
r2[6] = params6;

Object rules = xmlRpcClient.execute("execute", r2);
```

Note: I also found that **res_groups** table has a model named **res.groups** which is used by xml-rpc services. But **res_groups_users_rel**  table has no model.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it can help.
I was also trying to access the "res.groups.users.rel" table to get the groups the user was in.

I finally found that the model "res_users" contain a field named "groups_id"

Php code using Ripcord :

```
$gids = $ripcord->execute_kw($this->db, $this->user, $this->pwd,
        'res.users', 'read',
        array($id),
        array('fields'=>array('groups_id')));
```

$gids['groups_id'] gives you and array of the groups ID for the specified user id

You can find the others availables models in the OpenErp web interface -> Settings tab -> in the menu Technical -> Database Structure -> Models

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You could access res.groups, that model have a field called "users" (it is an array  that represents the ids of the users that belong to that group).
Iterate that array and you will know the groups an specific user belong